# Add attachment in draft e-mail

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, email-attachments

I am trying to send a email including an attachment. This attachment should be attached automatically using the code behind at the time of opening the mail draft. Could anyone suggest the correct solution.

code I have used:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
string ExFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/Assets.xlsx");
Attachment data = new Attachment(ExFilePath,MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(data);`
```

I need to attach the file automatically in mail body.

Comment: Not sure about your issue, as Question is confusing. Why don't keep the file in your solution, you don't need to upload. Without upload, you need the file source from somewhere.(May be some storage account/your solution folder)

Comment: The email needs to be HTML to use attachment.  The attachment is added to the body by adding a new line that starts with two dashes.  See following for example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: I am getting the file from a specific folder in solution and wants to send it via email. To clarify the requirement, when I open the email application using windows location href, this file would be attached in mail body.

Comment: Are these attachments and files on your server already, or are you talking about client files? You certainly can't get and gab any old files on the client computer. If that was the case, then when you come to my site to view some cat pictures at my site? I would then poke  around on your computer and steal all of your files like ones called banking information, or passwords file or whatever. Thus, no one would ever use the internet again, would hey? Web code cannot in ANY way touch, grab, use, see files from the client side computer - the exception is the USER selecting files for up-load.